# I need help resorting this array

Tags: java, arrays

The String array is currently ordered by odd indexes followed by even indexes.

For instance, let this array visualize what I mean: {a, c, e, b, d, f}. (index 0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5).
I'm trying to sort the array back into the order {a, b, c, d, e, f}. (index 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

It has to work for arrays.length that are odd as well. ex: {a, c, e, g, b, d, f} --> {a, b, c, d, e, f, g} length = 7

Also, I'm trying to focus on the indexes and not what the Strings actually are because in my program they aren't just abc's or sort-able by alphabetizing them.

I could really use some help because I'm bad at sorting algorithms. Time complexity doesn't matter to me all that much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure what language you're working in, so I'll write it in Java so it's easier to reduce into other languages.

```
//import java.util.Arrays;

public static String[] unscramble(String[] scrambledStrArr){
   String[] unscramble = new String[scrambledStrArr.length];
   String[] evens = Arrays.copyOfRange(scrambledStrArr, 0, scrambledStrArr.length/2); // note that we can use int truncation here to our benefit
   String[] odds = Arrays.copyOfRange(scrambledStrArr, (scrambledStrArr.length/2)+1, scrambledStrArr.length);
   int evensIndex = 0, oddsIndex = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < unscramble.length; i++;){
      if(i%2==0){
         unscramble[i] = evens[evensIndex];
         evensIndex++;
      } else {
         unscramble[i] = evens[oddsIndex];
         oddsIndex++;
      }
   }
}
```

Please note that there are definitely more efficient ways to do this (look at aksommerville's answer), but this is probably the easiest to read.

Comment: Nice, Thanks for your help!! Your code almost solved the problem, but you provided me the idea of how I can tweak it to make it work just right. I seriously appreciate it ! PS: I am working in java.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of the same length, then copy in two passes with two counters:

```
for (idst=0, isrc=0; idst<length; idst+=2, isrc+=1) dst[idst] = src[isrc];
for (idst=1, isrc=length/2; idst<length; idst+=2, isrc+=1) dst[idst] = src[isrc];
```

The important thing is that one counter counts by twos and the other by ones.